# what is the difference between servlet container and spring container?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

What are the roles and responsibility of servlet container and spring container? Please someone clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 26):

They are very different concepts also if their names are similar.

A **Servlet Container** or Web Container (like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)) is an implementation of various Java EE specifications like Java Servlet, JSP, etc. Put in a simple way, it is an environment where Java web applications can live. A web server + Java support.

A **Spring Container** on the other hand, is the core and the engine of the Spring Framework. It is an [IoC Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans) that handles Spring applications lifecycle creating new beans and injecting dependencies.

Because a Spring application can be a web application, a Spring Container can "live" inside a Web Container.

For further information:

- about Servlet Container: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container
- about Spring Container: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: amazing explaination Thank you @davioooh

Answer (score 3):

Spring container is responsible for creating the objects, wiring them together, configuring them, and managing their complete lifecycle from creation till destruction. The Spring container uses dependency injection (DI) to manage the components that make up an application. These objects are called Spring Beans.

While Servlet container is basically web server or application server one who is responsible for creating and maintaining life cycle of a servlet like init, service, destroy in a nut shell. It has other functionalities as well in addition to maintaining lifecycle of a servlet.

Comment: If we create one simple spring web application we can find spring container(i.e,ApplicationContext/BeanFactory) but can't find servlet container in our application code.Please explain if any communication between servlet container and spring container when client send request?

Comment: Ahh no ApplicationContext is an interface in Spring.. and similar is ServletContext for servlet.. basically container means kind of a holder which holds objects ...

Comment: Almas shaikh: In Spring In Action book - **There’s no single Spring container. Spring comes with several container implementations that can be categorized into two distinct types. Bean factories (defined by the org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory interface) and Application contexts (defined by the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext interface)**.